# django-celery receive task but do not excute it

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery library, it's receive tasks probably but when I read the log its show me this message every time it's receive the task.

```
[2019-05-15 07:43:25,408: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 07:46:30,327: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 07:49:35,245: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 07:52:40,155: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 07:55:45,065: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 07:58:49,967: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 08:01:54,891: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 08:04:59,804: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-15 08:08:04,720: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
```

i run this command to start the worker

```
python manage.py celery worker -Ofair -c 8 -l info --settings=settings.settings -Q default,celer$
```

after search on internet no useful solutions I found, can some body guess what is the reason of this message and why it appear when the queue is arrived ?

Comment: Can you add your code and more information about what you need to do?

Comment: i made an edit you can see the question

Comment: hi! have you solved this issue? im facing same one

Answer (score -1):

so you are showing your beat log calling jobs  which I assume you have one using -f (although you have not shown)

you have your workers loglevel set but not using -f to see what that is reporting on picking up the requests from the beat service?

Might be useful to also state which OS you are using!

Comment: i am using ubuntu, there is problem in beat its do not fetch the task to rabbitmq i dont why, i checked the settings its looks right.